# How to use queries in model of cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I can use find query method in controller in cakephp.. Is there any way to use queries i.e update table in model (not in controller) ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use the `save()` method. Read the book entry on saving your data: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: Voted to close.  This does not fit the requirements for a question on Stack Overflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You mean using

```
$this->query("....");
```

in the model?